# Pylint custom variable-rgx doesn't catch camelCase

Tags: regex, pylint

The default variable name checker doesn't fit my use-case, because it catches single-letter variables that I want to be able to use, like `x` and `y`. So, I've written my own variable-rgx, `_?[a-z]+[a-z0-9_]*`. However, it doesn't seem to catch camel-case variables, and I think it should, because the regex pattern doesn't contain capital letters. Is my regex wrong? Or is Pylint using it differently from what I expect?

Comment: To be clear, I don't want camel case. I want Pylint to complain when it sees camel case.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to add a `$` (dollar sign) at the end of my regex pattern. `$` in regex means end-of-line. I find it a bit strange that I have to use this but whatever. So `_?[a-z]+[a-z0-9_]*$` works.